# Using google colab forms input as dropdown, can I put the read file and add on the total list?

Tags: python, forms, google-colaboratory

I using google colab to share my code with people who don't know Python at all.

To make it easy, I adapt forms into the cell which makes be able to select the options and parameters.

```
parameters = "A" #@param ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Unfortunately, one of the parameters has a lot of elements that can choose (more than 1000). I have that file of the parameter list as csv.

I want to know how can I that list after colab #@params such as below,

```
import pandas as pd

params_lst = pd.read_csv("file_name")

many_param_input = "ABC" #@params params_lst

manually_input = "ABC" #@params ["ABC", "ABC0", "ABC1", ..... , "ABC1000", .... ,"ABCn"]
```

I want to make it without manually writing (***manually_input***), just read a file and use that like the ***many_param_input*** line above.

If there is the way using read file as json input, please let me know how to do it

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You can't write markdown data from python code.

you can do it with [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/user_install.html).

dropdown example from NumPy array

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import numpy as np

random_numbers = np.random.random((100))

Dropdown_ = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=random_numbers,
    description='choose random number',
)
output = widgets.Output()

def on_change(change):
  if change['new'] > change['old']:
    print('bigger')
  else:
    print('smaller')


Dropdown_.observe(on_change, names='value')
display(Dropdown_)
```